# Accessing associated ActiveRecord models is empty and requires explicit reload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have encountered some never-before seen behavior in a Rails model. Given a Shipment model,

```
class Shipment < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items

  def can_add_all_items_to_work_order?
    return false if items.empty?
    items.all? { |i| i.assignable_to_work_order? }
  end

end
```

When I load a Shipment from the database in a controller action:

```
shipment = Shipment.find(params[:shipment_id])
```

And I invoke the method `can_add_all_items_to_work_order?`,

```
shipment.can_add_all_items_to_work_order?
```

The method returns `false`, because it thinks `items` is empty.

But there are indeed persisted Item objects in the database, associated with the Shipment, and this method should return `true`.

If I explicitly access the `items` after loading the object,

```
shipment = Shipment.find(params[:shipment_id])
shipment.items
```

And I again invoke the method `can_add_all_items_to_work_order?`,

```
shipment.can_add_all_items_to_work_order?
```

Now the method magically returns `true`, as it should.

I have never encountered this before. Why does the method `can_add_all_items_to_work_order?` believe that `items` is empty? Why do I have to do an explicit load or access of `items`? Shouldn't the reference to `items` in the first statement of the method,

```
return false if items.empty?
```

fetch the `items` from the database, just as it would if I executed the statement:
`shipment.items` from outside the object?

Furthermore, I cannot replicate this in the Rails console - the method behaves as it should there, and when I invoke `can_add_all_items_to_work_order?` in the Rails console, I see the log output for the `Item Load... SELECT *...`. Why am I seeing the database hit in the console, but not within my controller action, for the exact same statements?

Lastly, if I use some eager loading, a la `includes`,

```
shipment = Shipment.includes(:items).find(params[:shipment_id])
```

Then I observe the expected behavior: an invocation of `can_add_all_items_to_work_order?` returns `true`. Why is the eager loading necessary? Shouldn't the statements within `can_add_all_items_to_work_order?` load the `items` as expected?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I have overlooked that a reference to `items` is not a collection of Item objects, but an Item::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy. It will always be `empty?` until I do something to trigger the database load. Injecting an `all` invocation generates the database hit.

```
  def can_add_all_items_to_work_order?
    return false if items.all.empty?
    items.all? { |i| i.assignable_to_work_order? }
  end
```

It seems that, in the console, lazy loading is turned off. (Please correct me in the comments.) This is why I saw the immediate database query when invoking `can_add_all_items_to_work_order?` in the Rails console.

Now, the problem is that this method now will not work for new, non-persisted Shipments and Items, eg:

```
    shipment = Shipment.new
    shipment.items << Item.new
    shipment.items << Item.new
    assert shipment.can_add_all_items_to_work_order?
```

Because the `all` invocation within `can_add_all_items_to_work_order?` overwrites the `items` collection, and there are no persisted associated Items.

Given that I'd like to have this method work for both persisted and non-persisted Shipments and Items, I revised the method to:

```
  def can_add_all_items_to_work_order?
    if persisted?
      return false if items.all.empty?
    else
      return false if items.empty?
    end
    items.all? { |i| i.assignable_to_work_order? }
  end
```

I would love to see a more elegant way of implementing this while preserving the desired behavior!

Comment: seems like it should work this way already https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy.html#method-i-empty-3F. lazy loading (so that you can chain query methods) - it happens when you ask for output or for certain method calls. in a console, you hit enter - you're asking for it via [`inspect`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.6/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb#L1100). in irb you can return `nil` to see lazy loading in effect: `items = shipment.items; nil` nothing should happen, then asking for `items` should load it.

Comment: maybe these could be useful `items.loaded?` `items.size`